# Is there any good boost::filesystem alternative?

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

Is there any portable c++ library to work with the filesystem?

I know about boost::filesystem, but I need to know if there is any other.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you having problems with boost?

Comment: I'd like something that's not required to be built separately from your project. I'm looking for a simple, little library that lets me add the files to my ide project and just compile it with the rest of the code.

Comment: it doesn't get much simpler than `apt-get install boost-devel` or `yum install boost-devel`. If you're on Windows, [BoostPro](http://www.boostpro.com/download/) has installers.

Comment: Why are you compiling code on your iphone? :/

Comment: FYK: boost::filesystem has been merged to C++17. You can start using it as experimental feature, I wrote an example at http://carlosvin.github.io/posts/recursive-directory-iterator/

Answer (score 24):

[POCO](http://pocoproject.org/docs/) has similar functionality which you can find under Foundation/FileSystem.

Comment: You have introduced me with very nice C++ library. Thanks and +1.

Comment: +1 for POCO. While the entire library is pretty huge, you can just link to the portion you need to use (and whatever its dependencies are, if any).

Comment: While POCO is huge compared to most other C++ libraries, it is dwarfed by Boost's ~100MB package.

Comment: Why are there downloads for each platform? Shouldn't this abstract away each platform's specific features?

Answer (score 6):

There is at least one more solution worth mentioning - [`STLSoft`](http://www.stlsoft.org), a set of BSD-like licensed libraries, contains a cross-platform wrapper under Windows & Unix native filesystem APIs - [`PlatformSTL`](http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/group__group____project____platformstl.html) project. The benefit in comparison with `boost::filesystem` is no need to build anything, the whole library is header-only, you can simply include it in your project. The bad side is lack of documentation though, I spent quite some time to figure out how to use it.

Comment: The last time I tried, STLSoft did not compile on OS X. See my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717936/fastformat-on-os-x) for more details. The error generated by the library read `error: #error Operating system not discriminated. Only UNIX and Windows are currently recognised by PlatformSTL`, which is not a good sign.

Comment: That's news for me, never tried it on OS X. Really doesn't work. The reason seems to be that OS X does not provide predefined `UNIX` (or `unix`, `__unix__`, `__unix`) macro. I'm not sure it would work but you can try to add the option for `PLATFORMSTL_OS_IS_UNIX` macro in `platrofmstl.h`:

    `#if defined(unix) || \
        defined(UNIX) || \
        defined(__unix__) || \
        defined(__unix) || \
        defined(__MACH__)
    # define PLATFORMSTL_OS_IS_UNIX`

Comment: Thanks for the information---I just accepted your answer to my question. I think I remember manually defining `#platform PLATFORM_OS_IS_UNIX` or otherwise trying to work around the error, but came across more errors using the version of STLSoft that I used when I posted that question. I suppose that it is compatible with OS X now.

Answer (score 4):

What about QT's [`QFileSystemModel`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfilesystemmodel.html) or [QFSFileEngine](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfsfileengine.html)?

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in the SSVUtils library: https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVUtils

Answer (score 0):

I found that for an application which needs a lot more than the filesystem API defined in the language it makes sense to encapsulate the filesystem API yourself and on a per application level.

Because in this case you usually need some very specific features (you surely do on the iPhone/MacOSX) and this will be not very portable and also missed by boost and others. In this case you need to go a bit higher in your abstraction layer.

Today the operating system API isn't that bad anymore. Writing a wrapper shouldn't take long.